# How to loop through all the values in an array in C language?

Tags: c

```
int myd;
   int mym;
   int myy;
   printf("Enter your day of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &myd);
   printf("Enter your month of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &mym);
   printf("Enter your year of birth:");
   scanf("%d", &myy);

   int month [12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
   if (mym == 1 || mym == 3 || mym == 5 || mym == 7 || mym == 8 || mym == 10 || mym == 12){month [0,2,4,6,7,9,11]= 31;}
   else if (mym == 4 || mym == 6 || mym == 9 || mym == 11){month [3,10,8,5]= 30;}
   else if (mym == 2 && myy %4 !=0 && myy %100 ==0){month [1] = 28;}
   else if (mym == 2 && myy %4 ==0 && myy %100 !=0){month [1] = 29;}

   while (month < mym){
   int inc;
   inc = month++;
   printf ("%d", inc + myd);
   }
```

I get an error for inc = month++ because there isn't an l value for increment operand. I got what that means but how can I write the while loop so that it loops through all the values in the array?
I'm trying to find the number of days until someone's birthdate from the beginning of their birth year.

Comment: `month` is an array, not an `int`, so you can't increment it.

Comment: btw: `month[3,10,8,5] = 30;` is the same as `month[5] = 30;`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { do something with month[i] }`.

Comment: BTW; your `month` array is pretty pointless, explain it's purpose. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, please make sure you have a proper [mre] to show us, one that we can copy-paste without any editing or modifications, and replicate the error itself (and not have other unrelated errors). Then copy-paste the full and complete build output from that example into the question itself, and add comments in the code where you get the errors. And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour], read [ask], as well as [this checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to determine the number of days in a given month for a specific year.

You want something like this:

```
  ...
  int dayspermonth[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

  int month = 2;   // test for february, 2004
  int year = 2004;

  int days = dayspermonth[month - 1];

  if (month == 2)
  {
    // special case for february

    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)  // quick and dirty check for leap year
    {
      days++;
    }
  }
  ...
```

This incomplete code and **the check for leap year is only partly correct**, but it should give you an idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: Leap year check: `%4 == 0 && %100 != 0 || %400 == 0` ...